# Why isn't the long numClicks increasing when I click in this certain area?

Tags: java, long-integer, mouselistener

Why doesn't this work? dfiagdadowdoawihdoaihwdoahwdolhawlodh oiaw oidaod jowai doiawjdoia wodij aoiwjdoia wjdoiawj odawj oidajwoi djaow ijdaowi jdoia jowadi joaiw jdowai jodawi joaiw jawoi jdaowi oi joaiw jodawij oawdjoawijd oiawj oijawoi jdwoai

```
package rBP
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Main extends Applet implements MouseListener {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        this.setSize(1010, 360);
        long numClicks = 0;     //<--Long in question
        int autoFingerNum = 0;
        int faultyButtonNum = 0;
        int slickButtonNum = 0;
        int coolButtonNum = 0;
        int heatSinkNum = 0;
        int superButtonNum = 0;
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1010, 360);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(47, 47, 205, 205);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(50, 50, 200, 200);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(2, 5, 290, 30);
        g.fillRect(300, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(410, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(520, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(630, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(740, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(850, 25, 100, 250);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(300, 100, 400, 100);
        g.drawLine(410, 100, 510, 100);
        g.drawLine(520, 100, 620, 100);
        g.drawLine(630, 100, 730, 100);
        g.drawLine(740, 100, 840, 100);
        g.drawLine(850, 100, 950, 100);
        g.drawLine(300, 190, 400, 190);
        g.drawLine(410, 190, 510, 190);
        g.drawLine(520, 190, 620, 190);
        g.drawLine(630, 190, 730, 190);
        g.drawLine(740, 190, 840, 190);
        g.drawLine(850, 190, 950, 190);
        g.fillRect(307, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(417, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(527, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(637, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(747, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(857, 197, 86, 71);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(310, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(420, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(530, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(640, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(750, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(860, 200, 80, 65);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 12));
        g.drawString("Number of Points: " + numClicks, 5, 25);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("DO", 135, 120);
        g.drawString("NOT", 127, 150);
        g.drawString("PRESS", 115, 180);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 16));
        g.drawString("AutoFinger", 310, 50);
        g.drawString("FaultyButton", 411, 50);
        g.drawString("SlickButton", 524, 50);
        g.drawString("CoolButton", 635, 50);
        g.drawString("HeatSink", 754, 50);
        g.drawString("SuperButton", 851, 50);
        g.drawString("+1p/5s", 310, 75);
        g.drawString("+3p/5s", 434, 75);
        g.drawString("+10p/5s", 540, 75);
        g.drawString("+40p/5s", 648, 75);
        g.drawString("+100p/5s", 756, 75);
        g.drawString("+500p/5s", 866, 75);
        g.drawString("Buy: 10P", 315, 240);
        g.drawString("Buy: 75P", 425, 240);
        g.drawString("Buy: 300P", 530, 240);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 15));
        g.drawString("Buy: 1000P", 642, 240);
        g.drawString("Buy: 5000P", 752, 240);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 13));
        g.drawString("Buy: 10000P", 862, 240);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 12));
        g.drawString("Number: " + autoFingerNum, 305, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + faultyButtonNum, 415, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + slickButtonNum, 525, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + coolButtonNum, 635, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + heatSinkNum, 745, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + superButtonNum, 855, 150);

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if ((e.getX() < 50 && e.getX() > 250) && (e.getY() < 50 && e.getY() > 250)) {

            numClicks++; //<-- this doesn't increase, why?
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
`
```

Comment: What are you expections...

Comment: `e.getX() < 50 && e.getX() > 250` How can you expect both of those conditions to be true?

Answer (score 3):

Your code won't even compile...

You're `numClicks` is defined as a local variable within the `paint` method...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    this.setSize(1010, 360);
    long numClicks = 0;     //<--Long in question
    //...
```

Then you try and access some undefined variable called `numClicks` in your `mouseClicked` method...

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if ((e.getX() < 50 && e.getX() > 250) && (e.getY() < 50 && e.getY() > 250)) {

        numClicks++; //<-- this doesn't increase, why?
    }
}
```

Start by declaring `numClicks` as an instance variable...

```
public class Main extends Applet implements MouseListener {

    private long numClicks = 0; 

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
```

And then remove the local decleation from `paint`

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    this.setSize(1010, 360);
    //long numClicks = 0;     //<--Long in question
```

You mouse coordinates are impossible to be `true`...

```
if ((e.getX() < 50 && e.getX() > 250) && (e.getY() < 50 && e.getY() > 250)) {
```

x/y can't be less the 50 and greater the 250 at the same time...

You might also want to register the `Applet` to receive mouse events...

```
public void init() {
    super.init();
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

On a side note...

You should be calling `super.paint` before performing custom painting....but then I'd question the reason behind `Applet` over `JApplet`, but that's me...

**Updated with working example**

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Main extends Applet implements MouseListener {

    private long numClicks;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init(); 
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        this.setSize(1010, 360);
        int autoFingerNum = 0;
        int faultyButtonNum = 0;
        int slickButtonNum = 0;
        int coolButtonNum = 0;
        int heatSinkNum = 0;
        int superButtonNum = 0;
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1010, 360);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(47, 47, 205, 205);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(50, 50, 200, 200);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(2, 5, 290, 30);
        g.fillRect(300, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(410, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(520, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(630, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(740, 25, 100, 250);
        g.fillRect(850, 25, 100, 250);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(300, 100, 400, 100);
        g.drawLine(410, 100, 510, 100);
        g.drawLine(520, 100, 620, 100);
        g.drawLine(630, 100, 730, 100);
        g.drawLine(740, 100, 840, 100);
        g.drawLine(850, 100, 950, 100);
        g.drawLine(300, 190, 400, 190);
        g.drawLine(410, 190, 510, 190);
        g.drawLine(520, 190, 620, 190);
        g.drawLine(630, 190, 730, 190);
        g.drawLine(740, 190, 840, 190);
        g.drawLine(850, 190, 950, 190);
        g.fillRect(307, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(417, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(527, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(637, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(747, 197, 86, 71);
        g.fillRect(857, 197, 86, 71);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(310, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(420, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(530, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(640, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(750, 200, 80, 65);
        g.fillRect(860, 200, 80, 65);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 12));
        g.drawString("Number of Points: " + numClicks, 5, 25);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("DO", 135, 120);
        g.drawString("NOT", 127, 150);
        g.drawString("PRESS", 115, 180);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 16));
        g.drawString("AutoFinger", 310, 50);
        g.drawString("FaultyButton", 411, 50);
        g.drawString("SlickButton", 524, 50);
        g.drawString("CoolButton", 635, 50);
        g.drawString("HeatSink", 754, 50);
        g.drawString("SuperButton", 851, 50);
        g.drawString("+1p/5s", 310, 75);
        g.drawString("+3p/5s", 434, 75);
        g.drawString("+10p/5s", 540, 75);
        g.drawString("+40p/5s", 648, 75);
        g.drawString("+100p/5s", 756, 75);
        g.drawString("+500p/5s", 866, 75);
        g.drawString("Buy: 10P", 315, 240);
        g.drawString("Buy: 75P", 425, 240);
        g.drawString("Buy: 300P", 530, 240);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 15));
        g.drawString("Buy: 1000P", 642, 240);
        g.drawString("Buy: 5000P", 752, 240);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 13));
        g.drawString("Buy: 10000P", 862, 240);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 12));
        g.drawString("Number: " + autoFingerNum, 305, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + faultyButtonNum, 415, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + slickButtonNum, 525, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + coolButtonNum, 635, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + heatSinkNum, 745, 150);
        g.drawString("Number: " + superButtonNum, 855, 150);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 200, 200);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if ((e.getX() > 50 && e.getX() < 250) && (e.getY() > 50 && e.getY() < 250)) {
            numClicks++;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much! Sorry, I'm VERY new to Java!

Comment: No worries, hope it helped a little

Comment: Hey, it's still not working. Would you mind helping a little more?

Comment: Try the updated example.  If you want to know how to fix the flashing, the answer is use a `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method instead and then add that to an `JApplet` or you could just make use of the Swing controls/components insteads, see [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are contradictory:

```
e.getX() < 50 && e.getX() > 250 //Less than 50 and more than 250 - Impossible
e.getY() < 50 && e.getY() > 250 //Less than 50 and more than 250 - Impossible
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the numClicks as static

```
private static long numClicks = 0;
```